# XOR Neural Network not converging

Tags: neural-network

I'm having a problem with getting my XOR neural network to converge.  It has two inputs, 2 nodes in the hidden layer, and one output node.  I think it has something to do with my back propagation algorithm but I have tried to figure out where in it the problem occurs but I can't.  I have also looked extensively over all the algorithms and they appear to be all correct.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class NeuralNetwork {

    public static class Perceptron {
        public ArrayList<Perceptron> inputs;
        public ArrayList<Double> inputWeight;
        public double output;
        public double error;
        private double bias = 1;
        private double biasWeight;
        public boolean activationOn = false;

        //sets up non input layers
        public Perceptron(ArrayList<Perceptron> in) {
            inputWeight = new ArrayList<Double>(in.size());
            inputs = in;

            initWeight(in.size());
        }

        //basic constructor
        public Perceptron() { }

        //generate random weights
        private void initWeight(int size) {
            Random generator = new Random();

            for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
                inputWeight.add(i, ((generator.nextDouble())));

            biasWeight = (generator.nextDouble());
        }

        //calculate output based on current outputs of last layer
        public double calculateOutput() {
            double num = 0;

            num = bias*biasWeight;
            for(int i=0; i<inputs.size(); i++) 
                num += inputs.get(i).output * inputWeight.get(i);

            output = num;

            if(activationOn)
                output = sigmoid(output);
            else
                output = threshold(output);

            return output;
        }


        //methods used for learning

        //calculate output error
        public double calcOutputError(double expected){
            error = output * (1 - output) * (expected - output);
            return error;
        }

        //calculate node blame
        public void blame(double outError, double outWeight) {
            error = output * (1 - output) * outWeight * outError;
        }

        //adjust weights
        public void adjustWeight() {
            double alpha = .5;
            double newWeight = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<inputs.size(); i++) {
                newWeight = inputWeight.get(i) + alpha * inputs.get(i).output * error;
                inputWeight.set(i, newWeight);
            }

            //adjust bias weight
            newWeight = biasWeight + alpha * bias * error;
            biasWeight = newWeight;
            //System.out.println("Weight " + biasWeight);
        }

        //returns the sigmoid of x
        private double sigmoid(double x) {
            return (1 / ( 1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -x)));
        }

        //returns threshold of x
        private double threshold(double x) {
            if(x>=0.5)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }   

    //teaches a neural network XOR
    public static void teachXOR(ArrayList<Perceptron> inputs, ArrayList<Perceptron> hidden, Perceptron output) {
        int examples[][] = { {0,0,0},
                             {1,1,0},
                             {0,1,1},
                             {1,0,1} };
        boolean examplesFix[] = {false, false, false, false};
        int layerSize = 2;
        boolean learned = false;
        boolean fixed;
        int limit = 50000;

        while(!learned && limit > 0) {  
            learned = true;
            limit--;

            //turn on using activation function
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                hidden.get(i).activationOn = true;
            output.activationOn = true;

            for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                examplesFix[i] = false;
                //set up inputs
                for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++)
                    inputs.get(j).output = examples[i][j];

                //calculate outputs for hidden layer
                for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++)
                    hidden.get(j).calculateOutput();

                //calculate final output
                double outValue = output.calculateOutput();

                System.out.println("Check output " + examples[i][0] + "," + examples[i][1] + " = " + outValue);

                if(((outValue < .5 && examples[i][2] == 1) || (outValue > .5 && examples[i][2] == 0))) {
                    learned = false;
                    examplesFix[i] = true;
                }
            }           

            //turn on using activation function
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                hidden.get(i).activationOn = true;
            output.activationOn = true;

            //teach the nodes that are incorrect
            if(!learned && limit >= 0) {
                for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                    if(examplesFix[i]) {
                        fixed = false;
                        while(!fixed) {                     
                            //System.out.println("Adjusting weight: " + examples[i][0] + "," + examples[i][1] + " --> " + examples[i][2]);
                            for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++)
                                inputs.get(j).output = examples[i][j];

                            //calculate outputs for hidden layer
                            for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++) 
                                hidden.get(j).calculateOutput();

                            //calculate final output
                            double outValue = output.calculateOutput();             

                            if((outValue >= .5 && examples[i][2] == 1) || (outValue < .5 && examples[i][2] == 0)) {
                                fixed = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                double outError = output.calcOutputError(examples[i][2]);
                                //blame the hidden layer nodes
                                for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++)
                                    hidden.get(j).blame(outError, output.inputWeight.get(j));

                                //adjust weights
                                for(int j=0; j<layerSize; j++)
                                    hidden.get(j).adjustWeight();
                                output.adjustWeight();  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //if(limit <= 0) 
        //  System.out.println("Did not converge");//, error: " + output.error);
        //System.out.println("Done");
    }

    //runs tests for XOR, not complete
    public static void runXOR(ArrayList<Perceptron> inputs, ArrayList<Perceptron> hidden, Perceptron output) throws IOException {
        //create new file
        PrintWriter writer;
        File file = new File("Test.csv");
        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        writer = new PrintWriter(file);

        ArrayList<String> positive = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> negative = new ArrayList<String>();

        //turn off using activation function
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            hidden.get(i).activationOn = false;
        output.activationOn = false;

        //tests 10,000 points
        for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<=100; j++) {
                inputs.get(0).output = (double)i/100;
                inputs.get(1).output = (double)j/100;

                //calculate outputs for hidden layer
                for(int k=0; k<2; k++) 
                    hidden.get(k).calculateOutput();

                //calculate final output
                double outValue = output.calculateOutput();

                //keep track of positive and negative results
                if(outValue >= .5) {
                    positive.add((double)i/100 + "," + (double)j/100 + "," + outValue);
                    //writer.println((double)i/100 + "," + (double)j/100 + ",1");
                }
                else if(outValue < .5) {
                    negative.add((double)i/100 + "," + (double)j/100 + "," + outValue);
                    //writer.println((double)i/100 + "," + (double)j/100 + ",0");
                }
            }
        }

        //write out to file
        writer.println("X,Y,Positive,X,Y,Negative");

        int i = 0;
        while(i<positive.size() && i<negative.size()) {
            writer.println(positive.get(i) + "," + negative.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        while(i<positive.size()) {
            writer.println(positive.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        while(i<negative.size()) {
            writer.println(",,,"  + negative.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        writer.close();
    }


    //used for testing
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int layerSize = 2;
        ArrayList<Perceptron> inputLayer;
        ArrayList<Perceptron> hiddenLayer;
        Perceptron outputLayer;

        //XOR neural network
        inputLayer = new ArrayList<Perceptron>(layerSize);
        hiddenLayer = new ArrayList<Perceptron>(layerSize);

        //for(Perceptron per : inputLayer) 
        //  per = new Perceptron();

        for(int i=0; i<layerSize; i++) 
            inputLayer.add(new Perceptron());

        for(int i=0; i<layerSize; i++) 
            hiddenLayer.add(new Perceptron(inputLayer));

        outputLayer = new Perceptron(hiddenLayer);


        teachXOR(inputLayer, hiddenLayer, outputLayer);
        runXOR(inputLayer, hiddenLayer, outputLayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code has very peculiar structure and will be hard to debug. I would consider writing it from scratch, with more clear structure, less internal fields, and more actual functions returning values.

One major error (possibly not the only one) is your distinction between output and learnOutput in hidden layer. When you calculate activation of the output layer you actually use "output" field, while you should use learnOutput (which is the only one actually using sigmoid activation).

Furthermore - if you correctly restructure your code you could create unit test for numerical gradient testing, and this is what you should **always** do when working with neural networks/other gradient trained machines. In this case it would show you that your gradient is incorrect.

Comment: The entire issue was pretty much so with the activation function vs. the threshold function in there (few small other insignificant things were fixed in there too).  I was kind of confused on when and when not to use the activation function and threshold function, it was not clarified terribly well in class.  This helped out a lot and everything seems to be operating and learning correctly, thank you.

I did have a test implemented in there, I had just commented them out.  They are currently written to a basic csv file and you have to graph them yourself.